# Confuse about css float

Tags: css, html, overflow

I have a div and an image inside it

```
<div>
    <img src="logo.png">
</div>

img {
    float: left;
}
```

I can see the `div` have collapsed, the height have become to 0,
my first question is, but the image is inside the, cuz the div's height is 0,why the image still can be see?

I know the solution like give the div a `overflow` property, even to `auto`. But why it can solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a parent element will not wrap around floated content. (It would be annoying in many situations if it did.) So if you want it to do so, you need to force the container to enclose the floated element. `overflow: hidden;` is one way of doing it, though it's not always a viable solution. There are quite a few other ways of doing it, too, such as the "clearfix" method.

The `overflow` property works to contain floats because, to obey the rule, the containing element has to 'look and see' what's inside it. Normally, floated content is taken outside the document flow and mostly ignored by other elements.

Here are some other containment options for that div:

The "clearfix" method:

```
div:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}
```

Floating the container:

```
div.contain {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Using `display: table`:

```
div {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Using `display: inline-block`:

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Using `position: absolute;`:

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Some of these are more useful than others, and context will determine which is and isn't appropriate in any particular layout. Generally, I stick with `overflow: hidden` unless some content needs to hang out of the containing element (such as in a drop down menu), in which case I'll normally use the "clearfix" option.

Answer (score 1):

Floating elements doesn't affect the size of the parent element. As the `div` only contains floating elements, there is nothing that gives it height.

By setting the `overflow` style on the parent element (to anything but `visible`), you force it to contain its elements, so that they can be scrolled.

By not setting a specific size on the parent element, it will get the size from its children, and you don't get scrollbars. As the children are now contained, the floating elements will affect the size of the parent.

An alternative to using `overflow` on the parent element, is to add a non-floating child after the other, and use `clear: both;` on it so that it's below the floating children. That way the parent will contain the children because of that last non-floating child.